# why this (not set to an instance of an object ) error showing to me?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to make this code work by checking if there is a movie id in the link so it will render different text than if there is no id

```
@if (Model.Movie.Id != null)
```

[image]

Comment: The important question here is:  can `Model.Movie` itself be null?

Comment: hmm when i tried it says Feature is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or greater.

Answer (score 1):

Your Model.Movie object must be null in some cases, attempting to check a property of a null value will throw that error.

You could try doing this instead so you check Movie and THEN check the id:

```
@if (Model.Movie != null && Model.Movie.Id != null)
```

Comment: Thank u so much.. I feel stupid I was stuck on this for 2 days ;(